# Loading Application Image icon in to imageView Using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I m making fileManager app and i load drawble image icon in my image view using glide:
this is my drawble method:

```
 public Drawable getapkIcon(String filepath){

    PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(filepath, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        appInfo.sourceDir =filepath;
        appInfo.publicSourceDir = filepath;
    }
    Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());

    return icon;

}
```

glide performs:

```
Glide
.with(mContext)
.load(mIconRepository
.getapkIcon(filepath))
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.into(holder.apkImage);
```

which shows error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type class 
 android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable. You must provide a Model of a
 type for which there is a registered ModelLoader, if you are using a custom
 model, you must first call Glide#register with a ModelLoaderFactory for your custom model class
```

how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, you can't use **Glide** `load` method with `BitmapDrawable`, it's not a supported type.

You could implement model loader/decoder for it, but I think it's not worth to solve this problem.

Why don't you use simple `ImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)` if your drawable is already in your local file system?

Comment: because its take some 0.5s time to load the image